# how to reduce array result from scraper and send to discord with specific lenght?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
case "scrape": 
    message.channel.send('Scraper is running'); 
    console.log('Scraper is running');
    
    ineed.collect.images.from('https://www.picuki.com/profile/dokteranime', function (err, response, result) { 
        console.log(result);
        var a = JSON.stringify(result);
        
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[a.length]=a[i];
        }

        a.length -= 10;
        message.channel.send(a);
     });
     break;
```

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
> content: Must be 2000 or fewer in length.

how to reduce the array result?
or any suggestions for using another **scraper**?

im using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) library [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/) and **scraper** [ineed.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ineed)

Comment: it's a string. just take a substring and send that

Comment: sure,but i got error on the discord.js library. it say _Must be 2000 or fewer in length._
idk how to reduce it @Klaycon

Comment: i'm aware that you got an error saying your string must be 2000 or fewer characters in length, that's why i recommended taking a substring (which would make the result whatever length you choose)

Comment: you may simply google how to take a substring in javascript

Comment: thanks dude,its work @Klaycon